# Making catalogue in Illustrator (Saving options?)

Tags: pdf, printing, save, adobe-illustrator

I have an old catalogue which I am editing so it's up-to-date. The old catalogue is on 66 pages and comes up to 140mb.

I have so far made 5 pages for the new version of the catalogue and I'm already up to 67mb. At the moment I use the "High Quality Print" option when I save the catalogue as a PDF, but it still seems like an awful big size for only 5 pages, considering the other catalogue is 66 pages and only 140mb(without any significant loss in quality it seems like).

I chose the High Quality Print option since I will print the catalogue later on, but what are the optimal saving options to keep the file size down while getting good enough quality to print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the "Preserve Illustrator Editability" box, and you may see a big reduction in file size when outputting the PDF files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It came down to 7,6mb so this was definitely what I was looking for!